# When does Twilio expire cookies in programmable SMS?

Tags: session, cookies, sms, twilio

I'm working on a system that's using Twilio to receive incoming SMS, My question is how long does Twilio wait before expiring cookies given to it and can I set a custom expiration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that Twilio expires the cookie after 4 hours of inactivity and there might be no way of setting a custom expiration. [Twilio Support](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223136287-How-do-Twilio-cookies-work-)